# My while doesn't break when it should also with the condition difficoltà <= difficoltà*2

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is my code. Please help me to correct it. Thanks!
I made a game where you have to memorize if you have seen a number or not. And when you finish you win.

```
import random
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,50):
  n = random.randint(1,50)
  if n in randomlist:
    continue
  else:
    randomlist.append(n)
life=3
punti=0
numeri_visti=[]
difficoltà= int(input("Quanti numeri vuoi indovinare? "))

while life > 0 and difficoltà <= difficoltà*2:
  numero = str(random.choice(randomlist))
  check = len(numeri_visti)
  print(numero)
  risposta=input("Hai già visto questo numero: ")
  if risposta == "SI" and numero in numeri_visti:
    punti= punti+1
    difficoltà= difficoltà+1
    print(difficoltà)
  elif risposta == "NO" and numero not in randomlist:
    numeri_visti.append(numero)
    punti= punti+1
    difficoltà= difficoltà+1
    print(difficoltà)
  else:
    life= life-1

if check==difficoltà:
  print("Hai completato il gioco, sei un asso della memoria!!!")
else:
  print("Mi dispiace hai perso, ma non arrenderti hai comunque fatto: ",punti," punti !!!")
```

Comment: It appears that `difficoltà` only takes on non-negative integer values.  What value are you imagining that it might have, such that `difficoltà <= difficoltà*2` would be false?

Comment: The only situation where `difficoltà <= max_difficoltà` would be False is when `difficoltà` is negative.  I suspect that this is not what you intended to do because `difficoltà < 0` would have been much simpler.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the difficulty limit should be twice the original difficulty, you need to save that at the beginning. Because you keep increasing `difficoltà`, so `difficoltà*2` also increases when compare them.

```
difficoltà= int(input("Quanti numeri vuoi indovinare? "))
max_difficoltà = difficoltà*2

while life > 0 and difficoltà <= max_difficoltà:
```